# Java FontMetrics.getStringBounds(...) return different results depending on Graphics2D

Tags: java, fonts, text-rendering

FontMetrics.getStringBounds() returns different results for same String, same Font depending on whether I get the FontMetrics from a Graphics Object from the screen (i.e. from a BufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()) or from a BufferedImage that was obtained with:

```
Component.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, imageTransperencyMode);
```

Or just by directly instantiating a new BufferedImage.
This seems to happen when Windows 10 is set to use scaling.
This is very annoying because it means text I pre-render to an image (for quicker display later) will be
slightly different from text rendered directly to the screen. (Especially with regard to text layout (e.g. word-wrapping)).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: How are you getting a FontMetrics from a BufferedImage?

Comment: BufferedImage.getGraphics().getFontMetrics()

Comment: That is correct behavior.  A BufferedImage, regardless of where it came from, has no knowledge of the screen or its resolution.  Can you not save the FontMetrics you obtained from the BufferStrategy’s Graphics in a field?

Comment: That is a good idea however I would be weary of re-using things like that, that I get from a Graphics Object. I will try it and it will probably work but later might turn out to create some other problem or actually not work in some other situation. It's an idea though. Thanks!

Comment: I think a FontMetrics is valid past the lifetime of the Graphics from which it was obtained.  I’m nearly certain that a FontRenderContext is.